# local configuration for grunt

Tags: configuration, gruntjs

I'm trying to come up with a way to keep either sensitive or local configuration for grunt out of the repository.

For example, I'd like to have a custom dist directory on local machine

what I've done so far is this:

```
dist: require('./local.conf.json').distPath || 'dist'
```

which works fine when I define a local.conf.json file, but I don't won't this to be mandatory and so I'm wondering if there's a way for require not to throw/end a task if local.conf.json is not found, or maybe there's a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the file is present synchronously:

```
var fs = require('fs');
...
dist: (fs.existsSync('./local.conf.json') ? require('./local.conf.json').distPath : 'dist')
```

Or even better - have the default config and your local config in separate js files and load them in the beginning of your gruntfile and if the `local.config.js` is not present then fallback to the `default.config.js`.